# Uploadify in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, uploadify, swfupload

I use uplodify to upload files in zend.

```
<link href="/uploadify/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {    
      $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '/upload/upload',
        'cancelImg': '/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder': '/uploadify/uploads',
        'auto': true
      });


});
 </script>
 <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
```

This code is in view part index.phtml.
But when i run my web application i see in my web devloper tool it shows in console

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/upload/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1317192234400
```

Help me to solv this problem....

Answer (score 4):

"Some of the option names have changed in v3 to be more intuitive. The 'uploader' option should now point to the php script. The 'swf' option will point to the flash file. "

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7296/uploader-being-rewritten-in-v3.0.0/p1

part of code:

```
$("#gallery").uploadify({

    id : jQuery(this).attr('id'), 
    langFile : 'http://www.static-xxx.nu/uploader/uploadifyLang_en.js',
    swf : 'http://www.static-xxx.nu/uploader/uploadify.swf', 
    uploader : '/uploadify/galleri.php',
```

Answer (score 2):

The path specified is wrong somewhere.

In jquery function, it is given as;

`'uploader': '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',`

Check from where request is going for "upload/uploadify.swf" to get a 404 error.

also, if you are using a .htaccess file, make sure the request for these files are not denied.